# using r to compare grouped data to a constant value similar to mu=100 for student t test

Tags: r, anova, posthoc

I have a dataset which contains the percentage viability of cells after treatment with a drug. As there are more than 3 concentrations I've analysed the data with ANOVA. I want to then compare each group to a set control. So if one group has a mean value of 95% is there a significant difference to a value I input (100%)? If I just add the value 100 to the dataset itself, R has a fit and gives errors when carrying out normality tests and the ANOVA as either there isn't the same number of groups of it (for the other concentrations there are three values each)

```
Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `95% CI (lower) = round(t.test(dense ~ 1)$conf.int[1], 1)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 7: Conc = seeding, Exposure = "48 hour".
Caused by error in `t.test.default()`:
! not enough 'x' observations
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

or if I input 100 three times I get an error about a constant value therefore means etc cant be calculated.

```
Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `95% CI (lower) = round(t.test(dense ~ 1)$conf.int[1], 1)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 7: Conc = seeding, Exposure = "48 hour".
Caused by error in `t.test.default()`:
! data are essentially constant
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

When doing the ANOVA with one input of the value in the dataset it gives me this error but will still work, the comparisons will also work...

```
Warning: Data is unbalanced (unequal N per group). Make sure you 
specified a well-considered value for the type argument to ezANOVA()
```

Is there a script where I can specify to compare the data to a specific value, similar to mu=100 for the student t test in R. Or a way to add the value at the end of analysis for anova and comparisons but not for normaility?

Or how do others analyse data for cell viability or drug responses and comparing to 100?

Edited to include below script and error messages

```
Replicate<-seq(1:3)
"ten"<-c(80.2, 81.4, 90.1)
"one"<-c(85.6,85, 87.3)
"pointfive"<-c(91, 97.4, 98.1)
control<-c(100,100,100)
Trial<-data.frame(Replicate, ten, one, pointfive) #Trial is a name made up the dataframe is the function
View(Trial) 

Trialminus<-data.frame(Replicate, ten, one, pointfive)



###transform to long
trial_l<-gather(Trial, Conc, viability, 2:5)
View(trial_l)

trial_minus_l<-gather(Trialminus, Conc, viability, 2:4)
View(trial_minus_l)

###stat tests mean, SD, etc
(Stats_s<-trial_l %>% group_by(Conc) %>% summarise("Sample size"=n(),Mean = round(mean(viability),1),
                                                           "95% CI (lower)"= round(t.test (viability~1)$conf.int[1],1),
                                                           "95% CI (upper)"= round(t.test(viability~1)$conf.int[2],1),
                                                           "Standard deviation"=round(sd(viability),2), Median = round((viability),1),
                                                           "1st quartile" = round(quantile(viability, 0.25),1),
                                                           "3rd quartile"=round(quantile(viability, 0.75),1),
                                                           Min=min(viability), Max=max(viability), .groups='drop'))
```

```
Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `95% CI (lower) = round(t.test(viability ~ 1)$conf.int[1],
  1)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Conc = "control".
Caused by error in `t.test.default()`:
! data are essentially constant
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
>
```

Run without control group in dataset

```
         [,1]    [,2]       [,3]          [,4]      
Conc               "one"    "pointfive"    "ten"  
Sample size        "3"             "3"         "3"    
Mean               "86.0"       "95.5"      "83.9" 
95% CI (lower)     "83.0"     "85.8"      "70.5" 
95% CI (upper)     " 88.9"     "105.2"     " 97.3"
Standard deviation "1.19"     "3.91"      "5.40" 
Median             "85.6"       "98.1"      "80.2" 
1st quartile       "85.3"        "94.2"      "80.8" 
3rd quartile       "86.4"       "97.8"      "85.8" 
Min                "85.0"        "91.0"      "80.2" 
Max                "87.3"       "98.1"      "90.1"
```

When run normality test with the control group

```
> (NormS<-trial_l %>% group_by(Conc) %>% summarise("Sample size"=n(),Mean = round(mean(viability),1), 
+                                                           Median = round(median(viability),1), 
+                                                           Skewness=round(skew(viability,type=2),2),
+                                                           "Normally distributed"=ifelse(shapiro.test(viability)$p.value>0.05,"Yes","No"),
+                                                           "p-value"=ifelse(shapiro.test(viability)$p.value<0.0005,"<0.0005",
+                                                                            round(shapiro.test(viability)$p.value,4)), 
+                                                           "Equal variances assumed" =ifelse(var>0.05,"Yes","No"),"Equal variances value" =var,
+                                                           
+                                                           .groups='drop'))
Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `Normally distributed =
  ifelse(shapiro.test(viability)$p.value > 0.05, "Yes", "No")`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Conc = "control".
Caused by error in `shapiro.test()`:
! all 'x' values are identical
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Without the control group

```
> (NormS<-trial_minus_l %>% group_by(Conc) %>% summarise("Sample size"=n(),Mean = round(mean(viability),1), 
+                                                           Median = round(median(viability),1), 
+                                                           Skewness=round(skew(viability,type=2),2),
+                                                           "Normally distributed"=ifelse(shapiro.test(viability)$p.value>0.05,"Yes","No"),
+                                                           "p-value"=ifelse(shapiro.test(viability)$p.value<0.0005,"<0.0005",
+                                                                            round(shapiro.test(viability)$p.value,4)), 
+                                                           "Equal variances assumed" =ifelse(var>0.05,"Yes","No"),"Equal variances value" =var,
+                                                           
+                                                           .groups='drop'))
#
> t(NormS)
                              [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]        
Conc                          "one"       "pointfive"            "ten"
Sample size                   "3"                    "3"                "3"       
Mean                          "86.0"              "95.5"            "83.9" 
Median                        "85.6"              "97.4"              "81.4"
Skewness                      " 1.25"            "-1.67"          " 1.64"
Normally distributed          "Yes"                "Yes"             "Yes"  
p-value                       "0.4855"          "0.1711"        "0.2125"  
Equal variances assumed.1                   "Yes"                                    
Equal variances value.F value       "4.34849185"                      
Equal variances value.Pr(>F)            "0.06804075"
```

```
###ANOVA
> ###with control
> res.aov<-aov(viability~Conc, data=trial_l)
> summary(res.aov)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)   
Conc         3  529.6  176.53   15.38 0.0011 **
Residuals    8   91.8   11.48                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> ####without control
> res.aov1<-aov(viability~Conc,data=trial_minus_l)
> summary(res.aov1)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
Conc         2 229.72  114.86   7.503 0.0233 *
Residuals    6  91.85   15.31                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, homogeneity of variance fails when the control is included therefore a oneway.test anova is done. this does not work wiht the control

```
oneway.test(trial_l$viability~ trial_l$Conc, var.equal=F)

    One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)

data:  trial_l$viability and trial_l$Conc
F = NaN, num df = 3, denom df = NaN, p-value = NA
```

It will work for the dataset without the control so the script etc is not the issue there.

Is there another ANOVA test i could do instead for no homogeniety of variance when including the control?

```
####posthoc
##with control
DunnettTest(trial_l$viability~trial_l$Conc, control="control")
Error in DunnettTest.default(control = control, c(80.2, 81.4, 90.1, 85.6,  : 
  all group levels must be finite
```

Dunnetts test does not work on the dataset with the control

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've removed the bold from all the text in your question and added code formatting to the code. It would help a lot to see the actual code you're running, not just the warnings and errors. A little bit of sample data would help a lot too. Since your errors and warnings mention "not enough observations", "essentially constant" and "unbalanced", it would also be nice to see the count, mean, and standard deviation of your outcome by group.

Comment: Thanks for that @GregorThomas I've edited the post to include script

Comment: (1) you are trying to hack anova function to do a t-test. Comparing three samples against a fixed mean is just three t-tests. (2) For proportions, you shouldn't be doing a t-test, but a proportion test, such as binom.test. (3) if you want to discuss the statistical aspects of this, please open a question on stats.stackexchange.com, with the relevant context (explained concisely).

Comment: Hi @juod thank you for that input. I checked stats.statexchange and found this question which is useful.(https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50226/it-it-legitimate-to-apply-a-one-way-anova-to-data-that-have-been-normalised-to-t/50227#50227)  Agrees with your recommendation to do t-tests when comparing to a constant value and ANOVA without the control in the dataframe when comparing the treatments against each other.